# How can I flip a label (get the mirror view) in Swift (Xcode 6.3)

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview, uilabel

I am trying to flip (get the mirror view) a label text with CGAffineTransformMakeRotation. But still no progress.

This code flips it vertically but I could not flip it horizontally.

```
self.labelShowdata.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((180.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)) / 180.0)
```

Thanks

Comment: [Swift Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38547960/1634890)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.labelShowdata.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
```

*Swift 5:*

```
self.table.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1);
```

Answer (score 29):

Swift **extension** to flip vertically or horizontally any UIView:

```
extension UIView {

    /// Flip view horizontally.
    func flipX() {
        transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -transform.a, y: transform.d)
    }

    /// Flip view vertically.
    func flipY() {
        transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: transform.a, y: -transform.d)
    }
 }
```

Usage:
`yourView.flipX()` or `yourView.flipY()`

Comment: Swift 3: `transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -transform.a, y: transform.d)`

Answer (score 5):

For Swift 3 based on @Choppin Broccoli's solution:

```
self.labelShowdata.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need a mirror view you should use CGAffineTransformMakeScale:

```
self.labelShowdata.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1., 1);
```